# Youtube video not playing in InApp in android

Tags: android, video, youtube

In my application Youtube videos were playing perfectly in InApp. But certainly 2 days before I got the following alert message "Sorry, this video cannot be played" while playing the video and videos are not playing. I have tried different youtube video links, but no hope. If I use this code :

```
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                        Uri.parse("http://www.youtube.com/embed/Ai47z6qh8S0"));
                 startActivity(browserIntent);
```

Videos are playing then in browser. But I need this video to be played inside the application.

Previously I used the following code to create the youtube url

```
public static String calculateYouTubeUrl(String pYouTubeFmtQuality, boolean pFallback,
            String pYouTubeVideoId) throws IOException,
            ClientProtocolException, UnsupportedEncodingException {

        String lUriStr = null;
        HttpClient lClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        HttpGet lGetMethod = new HttpGet(OpenYouTubePlayerActivity.YOUTUBE_VIDEO_INFORMATION_URL + 
                                         pYouTubeVideoId);

        HttpResponse lResp = null;

        lResp = lClient.execute(lGetMethod);

        ByteArrayOutputStream lBOS = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        String lInfoStr = null;

        lResp.getEntity().writeTo(lBOS);
        lInfoStr = new String(lBOS.toString("UTF-8"));

        String[] lArgs=lInfoStr.split("&");
        Map<String,String> lArgMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        for(int i=0; i<lArgs.length; i++){
            String[] lArgValStrArr = lArgs[i].split("=");
            if(lArgValStrArr != null){
                if(lArgValStrArr.length >= 2){
                    lArgMap.put(lArgValStrArr[0], URLDecoder.decode(lArgValStrArr[1]));
                }
            }
        }

        //Find out the URI string from the parameters

        //Populate the list of formats for the video
        String lFmtList = URLDecoder.decode(lArgMap.get("fmt_list"));
        ArrayList<Format> lFormats = new ArrayList<Format>();
        if(null != lFmtList){
            String lFormatStrs[] = lFmtList.split(",");

            for(String lFormatStr : lFormatStrs){
                Format lFormat = new Format(lFormatStr);
                lFormats.add(lFormat);
            }
        }

        //Populate the list of streams for the video
        String lStreamList = lArgMap.get("url_encoded_fmt_stream_map");
        if(null != lStreamList){
            String lStreamStrs[] = lStreamList.split(",");
            ArrayList<VideoStream> lStreams = new ArrayList<VideoStream>();
            for(String lStreamStr : lStreamStrs){
                VideoStream lStream = new VideoStream(lStreamStr);
                lStreams.add(lStream);
            }   

            //Search for the given format in the list of video formats
            // if it is there, select the corresponding stream
            // otherwise if fallback is requested, check for next lower format
            int lFormatId = Integer.parseInt(pYouTubeFmtQuality);

            Format lSearchFormat = new Format(lFormatId);
            while(!lFormats.contains(lSearchFormat) && pFallback ){
                int lOldId = lSearchFormat.getId();
                int lNewId = getSupportedFallbackId(lOldId);

                if(lOldId == lNewId){
                    break;
                }
                lSearchFormat = new Format(lNewId);
            }

            int lIndex = lFormats.indexOf(lSearchFormat);
            if(lIndex >= 0){
                VideoStream lSearchStream = lStreams.get(lIndex);
                lUriStr = lSearchStream.getUrl();
            }

        }       
        //Return the URI string. It may be null if the format (or a fallback format if enabled)
        // is not found in the list of formats for the video
        return lUriStr;
    }
```

Please help me to figure out this issue.

Thanks Santanu

Comment: have u tried playing the same video using iframe.

Answer (score 1):

This kind of youtube link wont work on android application, although it works fine on browsers. To make it work on an application you need to get the RTSP link of the video first.
Refer to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8150074/how-to-get-rtsp-url) and see if you can find a solution there.
Example of youtube link working on android(I have tested this one):

> rtsp://v2.cache6.c.youtube.com/CjgLENy73wIaLwn_aij76iwMRRMYESARFEIJbXYtZ29vZ2xlSARSB3JlbGF0ZWRgnfqw4Jajx8xPDA==/0/0/0/video.3gp

Answer (score 0):

```
<iframe width="637" height="358" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/Ai47z6qh8S0?fs=1&amp;feature=oembed" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
```

try this  or

you need to have *hardware acceleration* turned **on**

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setData(Uri.parse("Video url"));
VideoActivity.this.startActivity(i);


     //And add below code in Manifest.xml file.

     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
```