# How to play a video from a RTSP link

Tags: android, streaming, video-streaming, rtsp, android-video-player

I want to create an android app which can play video from RTSP link. When i tried to play this through a media player, it showed an error message - "The Video cannot be played" I would be grateful if you can provide me a solution for how to implement this ..

```
   private String path2 = "rtsp://208.77.20.52:1935/dmm1/setmax";     
   Uri video = Uri.parse(path2);

    mVideoView.setVideoURI(video);
    mVideoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
    mVideoView.requestFocus();
    mVideoView.postInvalidateDelayed(100);
    mVideoView.start();
```

Comment: you can use videoview i hope this link help you

 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16005009/play-streaming-in-vidoview-convert-url-to-rtsp

Comment: Arun I am having same issue.   How do you solve your issue ? Is there any source code or tutoriol for rtsp player ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a similar question to yours here: [Play RTSP streaming in an Android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11274906/play-rtsp-streaming-in-android-app)

You might also want to take a look at the Android Developer page for supported media formats here:http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html

Without any code I am not sure exactly what you are stuck on. Hope this helps.

Comment: Now I add source code please check.