# Get rtsp link of youtube

Tags: java, android, youtube, rtsp

I have read number of answers like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8716146/rtsp-youtube-link) ,[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16005009/play-streaming-in-vidoview-convert-url-to-rtsp) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6520313/how-to-get-rtsp-links-android)

But these ALL refer to http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/VIDEO_ID

which is **no longer available**.  I want to `play and download youtube video` in android. But I am facing multiple issues like `youtube` is banned in our country. So it's not working. `What's the latest way of doing this.`

**So How can i play and download youtube videos using its URL?**